# Declare a var without initializing it... just yet

Tags: c#, .net, var

Is there a way or a trick to do something like:

```
var existingUsers; // This is not possible, but i need it to be global :)
try
{
    existingUsers = Repo.GetAll(); // This may crash, and needs to be in a try
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new Exception("some error, don't bother");
}

if (existingUsers.Count > 0)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

Or maybe an alternative for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why aren't you explicitly declaring its strong type instead?

Comment: If you need it to be global because you use some of it methods/properties outside try/catch, you assume it has some interface. Replace `var` with `ISomeInterface` like `ICollection` maybe?

Comment: @VivekGupta - you cant declare an untyped variable as `null`.

Comment: What type does `Repo.GetAll()` return?

Comment: How do I downvote comments? @vivekGupta looking at you

Comment: @Jamiec  - System.Collections.Generic.List<Users> NhibernateRepository<Users>.GetAll()

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This post cost you more than enough keystrokes to type the actual types instead of var for the rest of the year.

Comment: @Stefan I rolled back the edit you approved because with that edit, you don't have any question left. You then just have valid code with a comment saying it's invalid.

Comment: @hvd, It's ok. I'm new and I'm just learning the drill. I also don't understand why I'm getting downvoted... I asked this questions because I'm learning and don't know how to do this :)

Comment: @Stefan I don't have an explanation for that. Your question seems clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer here is to drop the use of `var` and to correctly specify the type of `existingUsers` outside the `try...catch` block:

```
List<User> existingUsers = null; // or whatever is the right type!
try
{
    existingUsers = Repo.GetAll(); // This may crash, and needs to be in a try
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new Exception("some error, don't bother");
}
if (existingUsers.Count > 0)
{
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must specify a type when you declare your variable - either explicitly or inferred. But you can do this which is close to what you want:

```
var existingUsers = (List<User>)null;
try
{
    existingUsers = Repo.GetAll();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new Exception("some error, don't bother");
}
if (existingUsers.Count() > 0)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: You dont need to do that just replace `var` with the type: `List<User> existingUsers = null`. and remove `var` from inside the `try..catch`

Comment: You can even omit the `= null`: `List<User> existingUsers;` is fine. It doesn't need to be initialised since its value is not used before it's assigned to.

Comment: @Jamiec - Yes, I appreciate that. The OP started with the idea that he wanted a `var` - I just kept that theme. It would be exceedingly odd that I knew the `var x =` syntax, but not the `List<User> x =` syntax, don't you think?

Comment: @hvd - The `null` is necessary if I was trying to keep the `var`.

Comment: @Jamiec - Good catch on the `var` in the `try` - I did miss that. :-)

Comment: The drawback of this way is that it initializes the variable to a potentially faulty value (`null`), so it removes the static check of whether the variable is initailized later on. It doesn't really matter in this instance, but it could hide a bug if the method flow was a little more complicated (a branch where you should initialize the variable but don't for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to be global because you use some of its methods/properties outside try/catch, you assume it has some interface (`ICollection` for example):

```
ICollection existingUsers; 
try
{
    existingUsers = Repo.GetAll(); // This may crash, and needs to be in a try
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new Exception("some error, don't bother");
}  
if (existingUsers.Count > 0)
{
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to having the variable in the outer scope, consider doing all the handling inside the `try` block:

```
try
{
    var existingUsers = Repo.GetAll(); // This may crash, and needs to be in a try
    if (existingUsers.Count > 0)
    {
      // Some code
    }

    return existingUsers;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new Exception("some error, don't bother");
}
```

This works quite well, for example, if you want to return the value (as I indicated in the modified example).

I would also recommend catching a specific exception (like `RepositoryOperationFailedException`) to distinguish this case from the one where your "*some code*" fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object` instead, and assign that later with/without casting.

```
            object var1;
            switch (v)
            {
                case 1:
                    var1 = "String";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    var1 = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "declare a `var`" in C#. The `var` keyword does not do anything special. It's just a shortcut telling the compiler "hey, I should put a type here, but I will let you choose the type yourself because I'm lazy/I'm unsure of the type/it would be redundant with the declaration". When you write

```
var i = 0;
```

It's exactly the same as writing

```
int i = 0;
```

And if you place your mouse over the `var` in most IDEs, the intellisense will tell you it's just a placeholder for `ìnt`.

Now consider this line

```
var myVariable;
```

What is var supposed to be here? `string`, `object`, `int`, `MyClass`, `IMyInterface`? The compiler has no way to know, so it cannot allow it. You will have to fill in the right type yourself.

Now your code should just be

```
List<User> existingUsers; // This is not possible, but i need it to be global :)
try
{
    existingUsers = Repo.GetAll(); // This may crash, and needs to be in a try
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new Exception("some error, don't bother");
}

if (existingUsers.Count > 0)
{
    //some code
}
```

And that will achieve exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, if you know the concrete type you need `existingUsers` to be, you can just declare `existingUsers` to be of that type.

```
List<User> existingUsers;
```

In a few rare cases, you may want the type of `Repo.GetAll()` without writing it out, for example if the type's name is an unreadable mess with multiple levels of generic type arguments. In those cases, you can write

```
var existingUsers = true ? null : Repo.GetAll();
```

but please *only* do this if you have absolutely no other option, and add a comment describing why you are doing this.

Comment: I fail to see any case where you would have to resort to this (I thought anonymous type at first, but methods can't have anonymous types in their signatures, so that's out). Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: @Falanwe "have to" is a bit strong, but in poorly-designed functions returning classes such as `SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<int, Dictionary<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>, Tuple<int, string>>>>`, it's a whole lot more readable to not write out that type.

Comment: @Falanwe Methods can return anonymous types, BTW, if the return type is a generic type argument that also appears in the parameters. `var x = true ? null : new { i = 1 }; x = new[] { new { i = 1 }, new { i = 2 } }.First();` (untested, but the idea should be clear).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of the anonymous generic type.

Answer (score 0):

I realise the answer to this has already been accepted, but I'd like to add something to the discussion...

When writing try/catch logic, I sometimes find it clearer to separate the try/catch logic from the usage logic.

For your example, I might write a `tryGetExistingUsers()` method which handled the try/catch logic:

```
private List<User> tryGetExistingUsers() // Cannot return null
{
    try
    {
        var existingUsers = Repo.GetAll(); 

        if (existingUsers == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("List of existing users is null.");

        return existingUsers;
    }

    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("some error, don't bother", exception);
    }
}
```

Then I would call it like so:

```
var existingUsers = tryGetExistingUsers();

if (existingUsers.Count > 0)
{
    // Some code.
}
```

Then the main logic is not polluted with the try/catch logic. Of course, this doesn't show where the rethrown exception is handled; but neither does the OP code.

Answer (score -1):

This is what `dynamic` is for: Just replace `var` with `dynamic` in your code.

But be aware that you give up type safety !

edit: given the approved answer and comments:
Yes I know that this a rather ugly way, and I admit I did not understand fully the real requirement of the question.

Comment: `dynamic` has nothing to do with `var`. They are wildly different beasts for wildly different purposes. I wouldn't let anyone considering replacing `var`with `dynamic` anywhere near my codebase.